# How to get overdraw counter value programmatically during automation test?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to have a automation test job that gets the overdraw value for graphics performance regression. But there is not any API I can find to do this.
I also checked AOSP source code, it appears that [HardwareRenderer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/HardwareRenderer.java) just compute the value on fly and draw it on screen. Are there some tricks I can do to get the value?

Thanks,

```
            HardwareCanvas layerCanvas = mDebugOverdrawLayer.start(canvas, dirty);
            countOverdraw(layerCanvas);
            final int restoreCount = layerCanvas.save();
            layerCanvas.drawDisplayList(displayList, null, DisplayList.FLAG_CLIP_CHILDREN);
            layerCanvas.restoreToCount(restoreCount);
            mDebugOverdrawLayer.end(canvas);

            float overdraw = getOverdraw(layerCanvas);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = attachInfo.mRootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            drawOverdrawCounter(canvas, overdraw, metrics.density);
```

[image: GPU overdraw]

Comment: that's a very old quesiton! I ended up change the AOSP source code and exposed the value via an API, then I use reflected to call the API on view. My use case was in automated test so this approach worked for me.